# Spring Boot Web / Tomcat refusing connection for specific network (Vodafone)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, https, router

I am using `Spring Boot + Spring Web` in an application for WebRTC Signalling. It is working very well and everyone testing is able to use it with their browser. But I discovered one case, where one person was not able to connect to my service via websockets. This person is using a TP-Link M7350, this is a Mini-Wifi Router that has a SIM Card (Vodafone) inside. I researched and debugged and tried several things in my application to catch the error. But I found out, it has nothing to do with my app or websockets, it seems to be an issue with TomCat / Spring Boot itself. I was able to reproduce the issue with this simple spring boot web application:

https://github.com/mxk1011/springboot-mini-demo

It is a very simple web application that outputs "I am alive" when accessing /test in one single Controller.

I cloned this app on a fresh server not related with any of my apps, opening port 443 with ufw and start it with `mvn -U clean spring-boot:run`. From all the different networks that I tested I was able to see "I am alive" when accessing /test on the server, I used different WiFis and Hotspots from mobile phones. But when I switched to the WiFI of this TP-Link router with the Vodafone SIM, I'm getting:

`ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` in my Chrome and all other browsers.

I switched the SIM Card in the router to a Telekom SIM card and restarted it. I was able to access the page and see the "I am alive". Putting the Vodafone Card into my mobile phone, I was NOT able to open the page and also got a timeout. When I turned on any VPN on my computer while connected to the router with the Vodafone card, I was able to access it correctly.

So for some reason this single Vodafone SIM Card causes that I am not able to connect to this Mini Webserver with the Github Link above.

For better debugging I changed the LOG LEVEL to TRACE. Here is what is happening when you are able to connect to the page:

https://github.com/mxk1011/springboot-mini-demo/blob/master/works.log

And this happens when I connect with the Vodafone SIM card to the server:

https://github.com/mxk1011/springboot-mini-demo/blob/master/fails.log

In my production app I am using a certificate from Let's Encrypt, for this example I am using a self signed key in a store (see github, it is the one I used for testing). Using a Let's Encrypt Certificate on the demo server does not change anything I also tried this.

I have no clue why this could fail. The person who I got this router + SIM card from is using it every day for his work and has no problems at all with it. I was also able to push the files to GitHub and open this StackOverflow Thread with it. Basically this demo app + my own is are the only pages I discovered that does not work correctly with it. On Monday I will go to a retail store and buy another Vodafone SIM card to find out if this is a general issue of Vodafone or anything specific to this SIM - I have to say at this point that I am no expert with this matters. Therefore I am opening this thread here and hoping someone has any idea how I can sort this issue, because when this happens on one device/router it can happen on many out there and I need my service to be up for all customers. Thanks for everyone in advance, I hope this information provided can help.

**EDIT** I know it is likely, that something between the devices, all the way over Vodafone up to the app is blocking the request and there's nothing to blame Spring web/boot. But as you can see in the logs, there is an incomming request from my IP adress from the router. If you maybe don't have a solution for my problem, maybe you have an idea what could help to find out more about it, maybe by using any tool / script on the server / client? I am open for any idea. Thank you!

**EDIT 2** To prove that nothing in the middle is blocking I set up a simple nginx server with https on the same machine and opened it at port 443. With the Router + Vodafone SIM I was able to connect to it via https. So for me it really seems like the point of failure is the Spring / Java part.

**EDIT 3** I tried now to access the server via curl -vvv to maybe get more information with this command. I accessed the server with it, but got this response:

```
*   Trying 1.2.3.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxx.com (1.2.3.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Fair enough, I need a certificate. I added a script to obtain a Let's encrypt certificate and convert it to pkcs12 to the git above. After generating it, I copied it to the classpath and started again. I did again curl -vvv myhost.com and I was able to access to without a problem:

```
*   Trying x.x.x.x...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to myhost.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=myhost.com
*  start date: Jun 21 10:08:36 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 19 10:08:36 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "myhost.com" matched cert's "myhost.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /test HTTP/1.1
> Host: myhost.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 11
< Date: Sun, 21 Jun 2020 11:11:27 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host myhost.com left intact
I am alive!* Closing connection 0
```

This works while opening the same URL in any browser FAILS with this SIM Card. With all other networks, no problem.

Comment: It is _exceedingly_ unlikely that the Boot application has anything whatsoever to do with it and much more likely that the intervening network is blocking it for some reason.

Comment: I had the same though to be honest. But how could a block in this case look like? Blocking a single IP or IP range? Then it could be solved by putting it on different servers with different IP addresses. I did that, on AWS, Digital Ocean + 2 other providers, it didnt change anything. What else could block, a firewall on my computer. But I tried with different devices connected to this router. The router itself? I put the sim card into a mobile phone and into another router, same result with diff. dev. VODAFONE as the provider blocking requests over HTTPS default port? I am sure they don't :-/

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Please take a look at the logs where it did NOT work. You will see an incomming request to the server from the IP of the router with Vodafone SIM.

Comment: We need more people like you on SO.

So you found that your Vodafone SIM makes the difference between works/doesn't work.
By any chance, do you also find that using TLSv1.2 versus TLSv1.3 makes a difference? I have a similar situation where TLSv1.3 doesn't work but v1.2 does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After long debugging I finally found a solution. Apparently for some reason the Vodafone network was blocking the connections to the servers that run my applications with SSL. By adding following to the application properties, it finally let through requests:

```
server.ssl.ciphers=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
server.http2.enabled=true
```

I hope this will help someone else facing similar problems.

Comment: Very useful in this matter to perform a self-ssl-test for the server: https://www.ssllabs.com/